# Error with define in Racket

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme, expression, racket

I just discovered Racket a few days ago, and I'm trying to get more comfortable with it by writing a little script that generates images to represent source code using `#lang slideshow`.

I know that when programming in a functional paradigm it's good practice to create almost all your variables with `let`, but I find that it introduces too many levels of nesting and that Racket's let has an overcomplicated API which requires superfluous parentheses.  I'm sure this is to remove ambiguity when using `let` in more powerful ways, but for my purposes it's just an annoyance.  Consequently, I'm creating all my variables with `define`, and writing blocks with `begin` if I need to (such as in the body of an `if` statement).

The problem is that I've repeatedly been getting what seem to be very mysterious errors.  I'm sure I'm just making some silly beginner's mistake, being new to the language, but I really can't seem to find the source of the complaint.

Here's the offending code:

```
(define sub-code (foldr ht-append (rectangle 0 0) (map internal-style (rest code))))
```

although what we're defining `sub-code` to seems pretty irrelevant.  If I replace it with

```
(define sub-code '())
```

I receive the same error.  DrRacket is saying that `define` is being used in an expression context.  I understand what this error would normally mean - IE that it would raise when you write code like `(print (define x 10))`, but I can't see what would trigger it here.

If it helps, this `define` is at the beginning of a `begin` block, inside an `if` statement

```
(if (list? code)
    (begin
        (define sub-code '())
        ; a few more define statements and finally an expression ))
```

The specific error message DrRacket is printing is

```
define: not allowed in an expression context in: (define sub-code (quote ()))
```

I thought maybe `define` isn't allowed in `begin` blocks, but I checked [the docs](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/begin.html?q=begin#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._begin%29%29) and one of the examples for `begin` is

```
(begin
    (define x 10)
    x)
```

So I don't really know what to do.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Definitions are allowed in a 'body' context, like in `lambda` and `let` among others.  The consequent and alternate clauses of `if` are not body contexts; they are expression contexts and therefore definitions are not allowed.

`begin` is special - `begin` in a body context allows definitions, but `begin` in an expression contexts forbids definitions.  Your case falls in to the later.

For example:

```
(define (foo . args)     #| body context #|)
(define foo (lambda args #| body context |#))
(define (foo . args)
  (let (...)
    #| body context |#))
```

Syntactic keywords that requires expressions: `if, cond, case, and, or, when, unless, do, begin`.   Check out the formal syntax in any Scheme report (r{4,5,6,7}rs); look for `<body>`, `<sequence>`, `<command>`, and `<expression>`.

Also, if you need a body context in an expression, just wrap a `let` syntactic form, as such:

```
(if test
    (let ()
      (define foo 'foo)
      (list foo foo))
    alternate)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Ended up just going with `let`, but it's useful knowing that `begin` can morph implicitly like that.  My intuition was that `(begin foo)` would just be shorthand for `((lambda () foo))`, but I guess it's more complicated than that.

Answer (score 8):

As GoZoner explained, you can't use `define` in an expression context.

What could you do instead?

Use `let`:

```
(if (list? code)
    (let ([x '()])
      x)
    ...
```

Or it would work with an "empty" `let` *and* `define`:

```
(if (list? code)
    (let ()
      (define x '())
      x)
    ...
```

But that's a bit silly.

Or use `cond` and `define`:

```
(cond [(list? code)
       (define x '())
       x]
      ...
```

This last way -- using `cond` and `define` -- is closest to what the [current Racket style guide](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/Style/style/Choosing_the_Right_Construct.html) recommends.

Comment: `cond` does not establish an expression context (according to my test in R6RS and the R7RS draft spec).

Comment: In Racket `(cond [#t (define x 1) x])` is valid and returns `1`.

Comment: Well, we all know ...Racket is not Scheme... :-)  In Ikarus `(cond (#t (define foo 'foo) (list foo foo)))` -> "Error: A definition was found where an expression was expected."

Answer (score 4):

Here's more details, from the Racket docs.

The [different contexts](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html?q=internal%20d#%28tech._context%29) are required because macros must expand differently, depending on which language forms are allowed.

As others have said, definitions are not allowed in expression contexts ("expr ..." in the docs), but are ok in other contexts.

In other doc entries, "body ..." indicates an internal-definition context ([guide](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/define.html?q=internal%20d#%28part._intdefs%29), [reference](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/syntax-model.html?q=internal%20d#%28part._intdef-body%29)), for example in lambda bodies, and "form ..." indicates all non-expression contexts, like in the docs for begin.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could wrap the expressions in (begin)
e.g.(begin
  (define x 10)
  (define y 100)
  (define z 1000))